# Google Product Schema errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, schema

I have added schema like this in page but when i test it on
Google's testing tool - https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/
It shows "**@type

Unspecified Type**"

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@type": "Product",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "name": "My Product Name",
  "description": "My Description",
  "brand": { "@type": "Thing", "name": "My Brand Name" },
  "image": "https://yoursite.com/path-to-image.jpg",
  "sku": "product-sku-12345"
}
</script>
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: If you use [Google's new validation tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), you'll see the complaint is about "offer", "review" or "aggregateRating" missing.

Comment: Thats right, how do i fix it ?

Comment: Add something like ```"aggregateRating": { "@type": "AggregateRating", "ratingValue": "4", "reviewCount": "250" }``` to your JSON. See the definition here: https://schema.org/AggregateRating

Comment: Thankyou, but products in my site does not have ratings in it. what should i do ?

Comment: This is all about rich search results. If you don't have anything for displaying as rich search result, then you won't have those fancy rich search result things (which is no problem either). Have look at the guide for [Product rich search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly use product schema structured data (missing offer). Please check https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product for details. So your minimal ld+json script should look like

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@type": "Product",
  @context": "http://schema.org/",
  "name": "My Product Name",
  "description": "My Description",
  "brand": { "@type": "Thing", "name": "My Brand Name" },
  "image": "https://yoursite.com/path-to-image.jpg",
  "sku": "product-sku-12345",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://example.com/anvil",
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "price": "119.99",
    "priceValidUntil": "2020-11-20",
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but products in my site does not have ratings in it. what should i do ?

Comment: ratings are optional. if you don't have implemented rating system at your site - you can fell free to use product mark-up without  "review" section.  Offers section is mandatory in this schema